# Не отображается форма в конструкторе Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Выдает следующее сообщение:

```
Чтобы избежать возможной потери данных перед загрузкой конструктора, необходимо исправить следующие ошибки:   
Экземпляры ошибки (1)  
InvalidArgument=Значение '0' недопустимо для 'SelectedIndex'. Имя параметра: SelectedIndex

1.   Скрыть стек вызовов

в System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.set_SelectedIndex(Int32 value)
в Global.formEditClusters..ctor() в D:\Dropbox\prog\TestAssistant\TestAssistant\formEditClusters.cs:строка 198
```

Хотя сам проект компилируется и работает без ошибок. Куда копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо вы в конструкторе формы пытаетесь установить свойство SelectedIndex списка ДО того как заполняете этот список значениями. То есть в списке нет элементов, а вы говорите списку "выбери первый".

Comment: Спасибо, так и есть.